# What code do i implement to have a time limit in my game

Tags: android, time

I'm createing a quiz that has a time limit and i dont know what to implement to have a timelimit in my level 1 class. what should i implement? can you show me a complete code?

am i correct?

```
private Runnable task = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);

    }
};
private void onCreate() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(task, 60000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do it. One way is to use a `Runnable` and a `Handler`.

First, define the `Runnable`:

```
private Runnable task = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Time limit reached!");
        // Execute code here
    }
};
```

Then you call it (say at the start of the level, `onCreate`) with this `Handler` and `postDelayed`

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(task, 60000);
```

The code within the `run()` method of the `Runnable` will execute 60 seconds after you call `postDelayed`

If you need regular notifications you can also use a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Comment: i really appreciate your answer. ill try it now :)

Comment: what if i want a time limit that if the player did not answer the quiz he will be intent or transfer in the mainmenu.class?

Comment: I cannot write all the code for you - the above solution + some way of determining if they answered the quiz or not (a boolean flag) + the standard Android method of finishing the activity/moving to the next activity will do it.

Comment: are u want to give time limit? if u want to stop timer after your time limit then use count down timer

Comment: Your code seems fine. I feel I've answered your original question. If it's helped please consider marking my answer as accepted, here's why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/226762 If you still have questions I suggest closing this off and asking a new specific question, otherwise it gets confusing and makes it hard for new people to contribute

Comment: nothing happens.:( i really cant do my time limit. im very noob in programming. hayyyyy... 3days i still finding this solution.